# IsEqual util type in Typescript doesn't work as expected

Tags: typescript

I write a IsEqual generic type like that :

```
type IsEqual<T, U> = T extends U 
  ? U extends T 
    ? true
    : false
  : false

type Test1 = IsEqual<number, 3>  // false, ok

type Test2 = IsEqual<true, false> // false, ok

type Test3 = IsEqual<boolean, true> // boolean -> ? 

type Test4 = IsEqual<true, boolean> // boolean -> ?
```

What happens here ?

And how to reliably check if a type is the exact same as another ? (not a subtype)

Comment: Also worth noting that both `IsEqual<boolean, boolean>` and `IsEqual<"a" | "b", "a" | "b">` are `boolean` as well, and `IsEqual<never, never>` is `never`. Also, enums with the same members will yield `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `T` and `U` in brackets in the body of the typedef, i.e:

```
type IsEqual<T, U> = [T] extends [U] 
  ? [U] extends [T]
    ? true
    : false
  : false
```

Otherwise, TypeScript will distribute the types and evaluate `IsEqual<boolean, true>` as `IsEqual<true, true> | IsEqual<false, true>`. Source: [this github comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29368#issuecomment-453529532).

Comment: Thanks  ! The missing part for me was that boolean, unlike other primitive types, must be considered as a union (true | false). So in this case, the distributivity of type will happen.